# Dense_Rank to return the latest date of a child record field

Tags: mysql, netsuite

I have a record A and a record B the A is the parent and there may be many B records. The B record has a Start Date and an End Date. I would like to do a date formula in a saved search for record A, and return the latest date for the End Date of a child B record.
Can I use DENSE_RANK for this? or is there a better option?
Thanks

I've discovered the GREATEST function that seems to work too. My complication now is that I want to compare the two dates but ignore either if they are greater than today. This is what I've got so far, but it's giving me an error.

```
CASE 
    WHEN GREATEST 
            ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tena‌​ncy_end_date}) > {today} 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE 
         CASE WHEN GREATEST({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tena‌​ncy_end_date}) > 
         (
              CASE WHEN GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tena‌​ncy_start_date}) > {today}) 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 
                  GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tena‌​ncy_start_date}) 
        THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END 
 END 
END
```

Comment: I moved the comments you wrote to my answer here and deleted that answer as it is more clear what you are trying to do. Please format the code as it does not seem valid.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ross

Comment: This final formula seemed to work CASE WHEN GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tenancy_end_date}) > {today} THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tenancy_end_date}) > GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tenancy_start_date}) AND GREATEST ({custrecord_es_lease_property_unit.custrecord_es_lease_tenancy_start_date}) <  {today} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END

Comment: @RossBush Actually, I realized that GREATEST does not work if there's two lease records with the different values for the same field. So I'm back to the drawing board so to speak...